# Need to change div output and javascript on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I am using to fade in and out 3 names at a time however when viewed on mobile I need to make it so that only one name at a time is faded in and out. My current code looks like this,

```
<div class="pre-pwr-rankings">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-80 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings">
            <section class="top-3">
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#1 Juan Pablo Montoya</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#2 Tony Stewart</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#3 Mark Martin</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="top-3">
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#4 Juan Pablo Montoya</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#5 Tony Stewart</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#6 Mark Martin</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="top-3">
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#7 Juan Pablo Montoya</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#8 Tony Stewart</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-33 mobile-grid-100 pwr-rankings-driver">
                    <p class="pwr-ranking-name">#9 Mark Martin</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-20 mobile-grid-100">
            <section class="pwr-rankings-link">
                <p>FAN SUBMITTED<br />
                POWER RANKINGS</p>
                <a>CLICK HERE TO HAVE YOUR SAY</a>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- END OF PRE POWER RANKINGS -->
```

The javascript used to fade the names is,

```
<script>
function fadeContent() {
    $(".pwr-rankings .top-3:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
        fadeContent();
    });
}
fadeContent();
```

This fades each "top-3" section at a time. On mobile (screen resize) I need to be able to show and fade only one name at a time. "#1 Juan Pablo Montoya" then "#2 Tony Stewart" then '#3 Mark Martin". Is there any way to do this since I already have the code in place to do 3 at a time? Thanks!

Comment: For checking for the screen resize you can use [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/). Although it's mentioned in your title, I don't see anything about resizing in your question body.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should use diiferent condition according to different width of window like

```
var wid = $(window).width();

if(wid < 767){
   //for mobile
  $('.top-3').each(function(i) {
        (function(test) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(test).addClass('animation');
            },(i*1500)+1500);
        })(this);
    });
}
else{
   //for desktop
}
```

..with that if you want to make div fade one by one thn your can use     "setTimeout classes" or anything like that

Comment: I have tried this using this method but I am not sire on how to change the javascript to show and fade only one name at a time. Can you lead me in the right direction with a code snippet of sorts?

Comment: This is my first time really using jsfiddle. Hope I did it correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/vh5pkch8/    Thanks for helping!